# Ran a MANOVA where Pillai's/Wilks isn't significant, but one of the DVs is very significant in my output table of between-subjects effects

Tags: spss, multivariate-testing, posthoc, manova, ancova

I'm a stats newb and was told by my professor to run a MANOVA for something I was checking out. Basically, I wanted to see if there was an interaction between ethnicity and a certain quadrant grouping for a set of outcome variables that are subscales of an overall measure (ders_tot).

An ANCOVA (one DV) already found an interaction between ethnicity and the quadrant grouping for ders_tot.

My MANOVA output is showing me that with Pillai's/Wilks there is no significance (p = .098 for both), but in SPSS there is also a table of between-subjects effects automatically generated that indicates strong interaction significance for one particular outcome variable (p = .003). The other DVs are far from significance (some as high as p = .27 or p = .66).

Is my MANOVA significance (or lack thereof) being seriously skewed by the highly nonsignificant variables? Am I still "allowed" to run analysis on that one particular variable included in the MANOVA that suggests strong significance? I also have data viz/chart output that makes a strong case for analyzing that particular variable.

(EDIT: BELOW PROBLEM HAS BEEN FIXED)

[Also, I've noticed that one of my covariates is always being run in SPSS with 1 df when it should be 2. I've triple checked the variable type and added labels and all that, and can't get it to run appropriately. When I run the same analysis in R, df = 2. This isn't affecting my sig. findings by much, but it's driving me crazy!]

Comment: This post has a few questions in it you should focus on one question only in each post. We can answer questions about SPSS syntax programming, but your statistics question is off topic here - you can ask it in [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!